# Get address with long and lat using google maps api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using the ionic framework and I'm able make a POST of address by getting coordinates using the https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place library, My problem now is when I edit the post in my database I have the long and lat and I want to prepopulate the adress in the field How do i do this

Answer (score 0):

Basically working directly with Google Maps API's is the easiest way.

One of the API's is Google Places, and it can handle almost anything you want, from auto complete widget feature to place picker widget.

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro

Using Google dev console you can obtain free key which is enough for testing.